# Why can't the <Fn> be assigned for shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I've searched for this question in vain. Does anyone know why the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key can't be assigned? The OS accepts all keys(even the keys that are set as shortcut by default, can be changed). What makes  the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key  different from other keys?  Is there a way to change this behavior and use it for shortcuts?

Comment: AFAIK, most laptops don't actually send `fn` keypresses to the OS - i.e Ubuntu doesn't know it exists as an individual key - the only key events that the OS does get is when the fn key is pressed together with other keys, such as volume, brightness, etc., and those are seen as a single keypress event. You can test this with `xev` in a terminal (assuming you're using xorg and not wayland) - `fn` on it's own doesn't generate an event. It's just a way for laptop manufacturers to cram more stuff & features onto a single key.

Comment: Make that an answer so that we can upvote it...

Comment: @JonasCz Make that an answer so that we can upvote it...

Comment: @xenoid Hi, you can use @<username> at the beginning of a comment to address a certain user so that the comment will show in their notifications. Otherwise, the other user may never know that you have commented.